# Broken Multiple Teams Sidebar in Slack Desktop App

Tags: instant-messaging, slack

For some reason, in my desktop version of Slack, I can't bring up the sidebar that lets me switch between my logged in teams. Once I've signed in to more than one Slack team, the Mac app does not display my team icons on the left-hand side (ie, [basic instructions](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201405046-Sign-in-to-multiple-Slack-teams) don't work. ). Neither the sidebar, nor keyboard bindings (Command-1, etc) seem to get me anywhere.

Feels like something I'm missing in the config. Or my copy of Slack is just broken I'm running:

- Slack Version 2.0.1 (3305)
- MacOS 10.12.2 (Sierra)

Any way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so all I had to do was remove my existing Slack application and associated files (see [here](https://www.uninstallmacapp.com/slack-removal.html)). Then a fresh install fixed this issue.